# what is this font? The name does not match

Tags: font-identification, script

So the font is supposed to be "Dancing Script" but it doesn't match it in the least.  Does anyone have an idea?
[image]

Comment: Hi ArtisticDesignPrint, we have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It IS Dancing Script, just with a lot of spacing and perhaps an outline to make it bolder. Here is a sample for comparison:

[image]

You can see the basic shapes are the same, but have probably been distorted a bit.